# How do I get all the inputs in a element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery. I'm trying to get all inputs inside a div element. Here is what I have coded so far:

```
$(".pros_earnings_delete_annual_earning").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(e.target);
    var parent = target.parent(".total-for-earnings");
    var inputs = parent.children(":input");
    console.log(inputs);
    $.each(inputs, function(index, value) {
        console.log(value);
    });
});
```

When I click I get this:

```
[prevObject: v.fn.v.init[0], context: button.pros_earnings_delete_annual_earning, selector: ".parent(.total-for-earnings).children(:input)", constructor: function, init: function…]
```

The each method does not seem to output anything.

HTML:

```
<div class="total-for-earnings" style='background-color:#ccc;padding:10px;overflow:hidden;'>
    <div style='width:160px;float:left;'><strong>Total for 2013:</strong> 
        <input type='hidden' name='pros_earnings_annual_year[]' value='2013'>
    </div>
    <input type='text' name='pros_earnings_annual_amount_mul[]' placeholder='0' value='10' size='8' style='width:80px;' />
    <select name='pros_earnings_annual_amount_sup[]' style='width:110px;'>
        <option value='Thousand'>Thousand</option>
        <option value='Million' selected>Million</option>
        <option value='Billion'>Billion</option>
    </select><span>USD</span>
    <div style="float:right;">
        <button class="pros_earnings_save_annual_earning" style="margin-left:15px; width:auto; height:25px;">Save</button>
        <button class="pros_earnings_delete_annual_earning" style="margin-left:15px; width:25px; height:25px;">-</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share the html

Comment: Can you show your HTML please? My guess is that no elements are matched, probably because the immediate parent doesn't match the selector.

Comment: you may have to change to `var inputs = parent.find(":input");` as `.children()` will find only direct children of the parent element.. same way `var parent = target.closest(".total-for-earnings");` if `total-for-earnings` is not the direct parent of the target element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
var target = $(e.target);
var parent = target.parent(".total-for-earnings");
var inputs = parent.children(":input");
```

to,

```
var parent = $(this).closest(".total-for-earnings");
var inputs = parent.find(":input");  //Unlike children(), find() will go any depth to match.
```

Comment: Just add find() and I will check it. :)

Comment: remove the ":" in front of the input. Because it selects event the "select" element.

Comment: Anyways it's perfect. Keep it if you like. :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply put:

```
var $inputs = $(':input',parent)
```

Will match all inputs in the context of the parent element.

You're `console.log` is outputting the jQuery object which represents each item in this collection, if you want the value of the input, just ask:

```
$inputs.each(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
})
```

Also, there was one other bug - `target.parent(..)` should have been `target.parents(..)` (plural)

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/3aJuZ/

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in this line

```
var parent = target.parent(".total-for-earnings");
```

change to

```
var parent = target.parents(".total-for-earnings");
```